# ngTable filter by date

Tags: angularjs, date, filter, ngtable

I would like to filter a table by date.
I need the dates formatted as follows: 22/10/2015

It works fine until the slashes (or dashes) break the search.
The code is:

```
<td data-title="'Date Created'" filter="{ dateCreated: 'text' }">{{res.dateCreated | date: "dd/MM/yyyy"}}</td>
```

and the controller:

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
          {
              count: 100
              }, 
          { data: response.data.res});
```

I've found some code snippets but they look overly complicated for what I would like to achieve. Just integrate special characters in the date filter.

Comment: what is your date object? what structure does it have?

Comment: Is this a dynamic filter (i.e. will it change in the DOM?) if not, you could just use a for loop to filter it before pushing it to the array

Comment: The date in the json is in the format "2015-10-12" @ukzs. The filter is not dynamic. I just want to be able to type 12/10/etc and filter through it.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.
Simply had to format the date from my database to be 22/10/2015 instead of 2015-10-22. Thanks @ukzs for pointing me in the right direction.